# What is Qtree in Linux? How it is different from normal disk space?

Tags: linux

For our project , we have raised new **Qtree**. But i am not sure why Qtree came in the picture. Why can't we order a new disk space rather than Qtree?

- Is Qtree different from Normal Disk space?
- What is the benefit for using Qtree over Normal Disk Space?

Comment: [Qtree](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1154894/html/GUID-022B7DB7-1933-4D5E-BC21-536B6EE02871.html)s are a form of logical filesystem on netapp SAN/NAS appliances.  I would guess that your disk space is provisioned from a netapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, thats a setup using by NFS with Netapp Storage (see library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1154894/html/…) This setup is used when you shared volumes, but you should use quota, so that one user/customer can not use the full space and stop others from working (avoid disk full error). Problem might be that users have problem to see a big volumes/free space but don't know exact there quotes.